# Filtering out parent records based on conditions on child records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two table with a psudo-schema like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Task(TaskPK INT)

CREATE TABLE TaskDetails(TaskDetailsPK INT, TaskPK INT, CompleteDate DATETIME NULL, TaskDetailName CHAR(30) , Status CHAR(10))
```

Notice that `TaskDetails` table has a `CompleteDate` column that can be `NULL` too and also its `Status` column has a few hard-coded values such as "Completed", "Cancelled", "In Process", "Waiting" ....

I want to write a query to find `TaskPK` ( parent table ) in two cases:
1- Parent has at least one child record that is **not** in the `Completed` Status
2- Parent has at least one child record that **is** in `Completed` Status **AND** its completion date has **not** been older than 30 days from today.

I tried to write it with `GroupBy` but it is not exactly correct:

```
select td.TaskPK from TaskDetail td
where ( td.CurrentStatus = 'Complete')
Group By td.TaskPK
Having Min(CompleteDate ) >= DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, using your description directly:

```
SELECT 
    TaskPK 
  FROM 
    Task T
  WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TaskDetails TD WHERE TD.TaskPK = T.TaskPK AND Status <> 'Completed')
    OR
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TaskDetails TD WHERE TD.TaskPK = T.TaskPK AND Status = 'Completed' AND CompleteDate >= DATEADD(DAY, -30, GetDate()));
```

Comment: still didn't work in this situation: Task has two detail records, both of them their status was Completed BUT their completion date was 2 years ago. It still return the task. It shouldn't , because its been two years

Comment: Can you check that the status column has no leading or trailing spaces and that the word 'Completed' is identical to the 2 comparisons that we're making on the sql statement? If not, we can remove trailling and leading spaces and force uppercase on the comparison...

Comment: yes thanks you were right. It was "Complete" in DB, not "Completed" ... worked.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `EXISTS` for that.

```
SELECT t.taskpk
       FROM task t
       WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                            FROM taskdetails td
                            WHERE td.taskpk = t.taskpk
                                  AND td.status <> 'Completed')
              OR EXISTS (SELECT *
                                FROM taskdetails td
                                WHERE td.taskpk = t.taskpk
                                      AND td.status = 'Completed'
                                      AND td.completedate >= dateadd(day, -30, convert(date, getdate())));
```

I'm not sure if the two conditions must both be true or only at least one of them. In the former case, you'd have to change the `OR` between the two `EXISTS` to `AND`.

I also down casted `getdate()` to a `date`, so that it loses its time component. Unless you really mean 30 day = 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 ms the results may otherwise be surprising.

Comment: as long as one of them is true I want to return the record

Comment: @Bohn: Then the `OR` variant as posted should do.

Comment: still didn't work in this situation: Task has two detail records, both of them their status was Completed BUT their completion date was 2 years ago. It still return the task. It shouldn't , because its been two years

Comment: If both of them with `status = 'Completed'` were from 2 years ago, then they might have a not completed status as well. Or you should give more details on the conditions. Maybe if a `status <> 'Completed'` exists no `status = 'Completed'` may exist for the same task? Probably think this through again and edit your question or ask a new one giving more details.

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve the required results using INNER JOIN too... please check below code...

```
  SELECT T.TaskPK
  FROM TASK T
  INNER JOIN TaskDetails TD
  ON T.TaskPK = TD.TaskPK
  WHERE (TD.[Status]!= 'Completed') OR (TD.[Status] = 'Completed' AND TD.CompleteDate > 
  DATEADD(DD,-30,GETDATE()))
```